# Is there any difference between passing an event handler directly and wrapping it in an arrow function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

Is there any difference between the way these 2 inputs use the event handler in terms of functionality or performance?

```
export default function App() {
  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* example 1 */}
      <input onChange={handleChange}></input>

      {/* example 2 */}
      <input onChange={e => handleChange(e)}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: But there is no reason to wrap it in your example (and wrapping it does declare two functions instead of one)

Answer (score 0):

Example 1 is "more performant", because it's only 1 function instead of 2, but that is absolutely negligible.

On the other hand, there is absolutely no reason to go for example 2, because it is just a redundant function, essentially identically to this:

```
export default function App() {

  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log( e.target.value );
  };

  const handleChange2 = e => {   // <--- this function is redundant
    handleChange(e);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">

      {/* example 1 */}
      <input onChange={ handleChange }></input>

      {/* example 2 */}
      <input onChange={ handleChange2 }></input>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Anyway, you might mean this as a general question, so some more remarks:

Example 1 is more flexible (IMO), and better keeps the JSX code seperated from the JS code.

E.g. you might decide to change something, like

- using `useCallback`,
- a custom hook, or
- changing the `input` to a custom component with a different signature,
- ...

...then it is nice to have the functions separated from the JSX code.

Also when you are changing a lot about the layout, moving JSX components around, it is nicer when you don't have to care about too much JS code.